# Nginx client sent duplicate header line?

Tags: http, nginx, microservices

I have a gateway where a request comes from a browser that makes a request for a microservice. Microservice makes a request after back to the gateway.
All this communication takes place within the framework of one connection. In all this communication, the same Authorization header.

Schematically there is the following chain of calls:

`Browser -> API Gateway -> Microservice 
                             |
                             -> API Gateway (from microservice)`

nginx gives me 400 bad request, in the logs the following error:

> 2018/06/20 23:05:15 [info] 22615#22615: *35468 client sent duplicate header line: "Authorization: Access-Token: 123213213213213", previous value: "Authorization: Access-Token: 123213213213213" while reading client request headers

I mean some sort of check for the uniqueness of the headers ... But does it really take into account the subquery application that goes back from the service to the Gateway API in the first NGINX session with the Gateway API?

Comment: This doesn't look like an error, to me it seems more like information message. It's hard to make assumptions without knowing your environment and configuration. In general I would start from checking upstream logic - why it returns 400

Comment: No, the aliases for code 400 in the logs are just below the level of information. Even if you look at the NGINX code, you can see there that after writing to the log of this message it returns exactly this error from `ngx_http_process_unique_header_line`